# Create image form byte array , add it in a PDF and email by backend job

Tags: java, grails, arrays, jobs

My question is that how can we create image form byte array without response.
currently I am using .

```
response.setHeader('Content-length', image.imageSize)
            response.contentType = image.imageFormat // or the appropriate image content type
            response.outputStream << image.imageData
            response.outputStream.flush()
```

but it gave error because we done have an request object as I am running this by back end job

Comment: where do you want to store it, then?

Comment: Image is stored in db but the PDF is made by back end job n send to the user..this pdf contains images uploaded by the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know how you are creating your pdf files at the moment, but one way would be using the [Grails Rendering Plugin](http://gpc.github.com/grails-rendering/docs/manual/guide/single.html) for pdf generation. With this, you could use any view/template to generate a pdf file.

To send these pdfs from backend you'll need:

A View:

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <h1>Your PDF Content</h2>
        <g:each in="${images}" var="image">
            <img src="${createLink(action:'displayImage', id:image.id)}" alt="${image.name}"/>
        </g:each>
    </body> 
</html>
```

An action in your controller:

```
def displayImage = {
    def image = Image.get(params.id)
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=${image.name}")
    response.contentType = image?.mimeType
    response.contentLength = image?.data.length
    response.outputStream.write(attachment?.data)
}
```

A grails job that sends the multipart mail (using the [mail plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/mail) ) with the rendered pdf:

```
def execute() {
    def pdfBytes = pdfRenderingService.render(template: '/path/to/your/template', model: [images: yourImages]).toByteArray() 

    sendMail {
        multipart true
        to "yourmail"
        subject "yoursubject"
        body (view: "/path/to/your/mailview", model: yourModel) attachBytes "yourTitle.pdf", CH.config.grails.mime.types['pdf'], pdfBytes
    } 
}
```

The code is not complete, it just demonstrate the basics.

Hope that helps!